# Allowing custom motion in a vim map?

Tags: vim

I have the following mapping that allows to paste over a word from the yank buffer. (cpw = change paste word): `nmap <silent> cpw "_cw<C-R>"<Esc>`

What I would like to do is allow commands such as the following:

- `cpiw` (change paste in word -> like the 'iw' motion)
- `cpaw` (change paste a word ->  like the 'aw' motion)

for any motion {m} cp{m}

Is this possible to allow in a mapping, so I don't have to write the nmap for each motion that I want to work with it?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: typo fixes. My solution below

After diligently looking into the map-operator I was successful in making a function that did exactly as I wanted. For any who are interested it is as follows:

```
"This allows for change paste motion cp{motion}
nmap <silent> cp :set opfunc=ChangePaste<CR>g@
function! ChangePaste(type, ...)
    silent exe "normal! `[v`]\"_c"
    silent exe "normal! p"
endfunction
```

EDIT - new version that might be better.

```
"This allows for change paste motion cp{motion}
nmap <silent> cp :set opfunc=ChangePaste<CR>g@
function! ChangePaste(type, ...)
if a:0  " Invoked from Visual mode, use '< and '> marks.
    silent exe "normal! `<" . a:type . "`>\"_c" . @"
elseif a:type == 'line'
    silent exe "normal! '[V']\"_c" . @"
elseif a:type == 'block'
    silent exe "normal! `[\<C-V>`]\"_c" . @"
else
    silent exe "normal! `[v`]\"_c" . @"
endif
endfunction
```

Comment: How do you solve the special cases when `cw` behaves like `ce`?

Comment: I do not solve this. The motion is still handled by vim. The motion of cpw / cpe is the same as cw / ce. You can correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It seems that `cpw` works differently from `cw` as it consumes the space behind the word: `first second` -> `newsecond` and `first = second` -> `new= second`. Additionally, if the word is at the beginning of a line, `cpw` with `new` in the clipboard does this: `first second` -> `snewecond`.

Comment: @Michael: See my edit. Try the new version and see if it fixes what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the new version. It solves the issue with replacing a word at the beginning of a line. However it does not make `cpw` behave like `cw`.

Comment: Do you have another counter example?

Comment: As I mentioned above, when replacing `first second` with `new` in the clipboard, `"_cw<C-R>"<Esc>` results in `new second`. The map-operator's `cpw` yields `newsecond`.

Comment: Actually, it is `cw` that works wrong. If you try to use `w` (word) motion with anything but `c` (change) it will get everything from current cursor position to the beginning of the next word. The only exception I can find is `cw` which is actually doing `ce` (`e` as an end of a word). So, for your issue, you could use `cpe` (change paste to the end of a word). Not sure why `cw` acts that way, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a way to define a custom operator, see `:help :map-operator` for details.